# Creating a react application build

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, npm

I am very new to react and I've a small working prototype of a react application I've deployed in AWS ECS as a docker container. This is working fine. I created this app using "create-react-app" with the below Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.19
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/build .
```

My .dockerignore file contains this.

```
/node_modules
```

I test this from my local machine using "npm start" command.

Now I understand there is also a build command (npm build) that must be used if I am going to create a deployment package.
This is where I am bit confused. Do I necessarily need to use "npm build" if I am going to deploy this? The reason I am asking this is because I already have a working prototype running in AWS. So what is the need for npm build here?

If the npm run build in the Dockerfile is what the actual build process is, then should I also use this command to test locally?

Appreciate if someone could throw more light on the build process of react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion might stem from the different use cases of npm start and npm run build in a React application.

npm start:

This command is used for local development. It starts a development server that allows you to see changes in real-time as you develop. It also provides hot-reloading, meaning the application automatically refreshes when you make changes to the code.
It's not meant for production use; it's mainly for development and debugging.
npm run build:

This command is used to create a production-ready build of your React application. It generates optimized and minified bundles of your code, making it more efficient for deployment.
The npm run build command is typically used before deploying your application to remove unnecessary files, minimize code, and prepare it for production.
In your Dockerfile, when you use npm run build, it's performing the production build to create the optimized assets that you'd want to deploy. The resulting build artifacts are then copied to the Nginx server for serving.

So, to answer your questions:

Do you necessarily need to use "npm build" if you are going to deploy this?

Yes, it's a good practice to run npm run build before deploying your application to ensure that you are deploying optimized production-ready code.
Should you use this command to test locally?

While developing and testing locally, you can use npm start to take advantage of the development server, hot-reloading, and an easier debugging environment. However, before deploying to production, it's crucial to run npm run build to generate the optimized build.
In summary, npm start is for local development, and npm run build is for preparing your application for production. It's a best practice to run npm run build before deploying your application, even if you already have a working prototype, to ensure that you are deploying an optimized and efficient version.

Comment: Great, that clarifies most of my doubts. I've couple of questions to add. 1.) In my case since I already have npm run build in my Dockerfile, I don't have to do anything else right? 2.) Do I also need to run "npm build" in my local and include the build folder in my Dockerfile?